# How to convert a swf to mp4/flv or so with command line?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, flash, flv

I'm going to convert a swf to mp4/flv or so with batch line in linux.

I've tried **ffmpeg**, **mencoder** or a perl script **FLV::info**. But all these convert just the video in the swf(maybe encoded by H.263 or so) to a new video, but **no movie clips**, not mention the ActionScripts.

I find [moyea](http://www.moyeamedia.com/swf-to-video-sdk/) seems to fit my needs(however, I need linux ones), but is there any free ways to do this?

Many thanks.